# My application crashes after SQLite databases are accessed multiple times. UNIQUE Constraint error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, unique-constraint

I'm new to Android development and I have been following a tutorial which creates a Twitter application that shows the users timeline and gives them to ability to reply and retweet Tweets for people they follow.

I have completed that tutorial, and I am now trying to implement Direct Messaging into the application. So far I have got my application to display the users timeline and a list of direct messages they have received, but when the user clicks between the main activity which displays their timeline, and their inbox eventually the application crashes.

The error message is as follows:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: messageInbox._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555])

I've searched for the error code and solutions online and so far have no luck with it. I'd be grateful for any help in resolving this, and also any other pointers related to the code I have here as I am new to Java.

It's running on Android 9 and besides some deprecated methods, I have used AndroidX.

The error occurs when the insertOrThrow method below is called in my MessageService class

```java
try{
     int count = 50;
     DirectMessageList directMessages = messageTwitter.getDirectMessages(count);
          for(DirectMessage message : directMessages){
                    ContentValues messageValues = MessageDataHelper.getValues(message);
                    messageDB.insertOrThrow("messageInbox", null, messageValues);
                    messagesChanges = true;
                }
} catch (TwitterException te) {
     String LOG_TAG = "MessageService";
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: " + te);
```

MessageService Class

```java
public class MessageService extends Service {
    //twitter authentication key
    public final static String TWIT_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    //twitter secret
    public final static String TWIT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    //app preferences
    SharedPreferences bioPrefs;
    //twitter object
    private Twitter messageTwitter;
    //database helper object
    private MessageDataHelper messageHelper;
    //timeline database
    private SQLiteDatabase messageDB;
    //handler for updater
    public Handler messageHandler;
    //delay between fetching new tweets
    //private static int mins = 1;//alter to suit
    //private static final long FETCH_DELAY = mins * (60*1000);
    private static final long FETCH_DELAY = 30000;//Update timeline every 30 seconds
    //updater thread object
    private MessageUpdater messageUpdater;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        //Setting up the class
        //get preferences
        //shared preferences for user details
        bioPrefs = getSharedPreferences("bioPrefs", 0);
        //get user preferences
        String userToken = bioPrefs.getString("user_token", null);
        String userSecret = bioPrefs.getString("user_secret", null);
        //get database helper
        //database helper object
        messageHelper = new MessageDataHelper(this);
        //get the database
        messageDB = messageHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //create new configuration
        Configuration messageConf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWIT_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWIT_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(userToken)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(userSecret)
                .build();
        //instantiate new twitter
        messageTwitter = new TwitterFactory(messageConf).getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MessageUpdater implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            boolean messagesChanges = false;
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try{
                int count = 50;
                DirectMessageList directMessages = messageTwitter.getDirectMessages(count);
                for(DirectMessage message : directMessages){
                    ContentValues messageValues = MessageDataHelper.getValues(message);
                    messageDB.insertOrThrow("messageInbox", null, messageValues);
                    messagesChanges = true;
                }
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                String LOG_TAG = "MessageService";
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: " + te);}

            if(messagesChanges){
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("MESSAGE_UPDATES"));
            }

            messageHandler.postDelayed(this, FETCH_DELAY);
        }
    }

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        //get handler
        messageHandler = new Handler();
        //create an instance of the updater class
        messageUpdater = new MessageUpdater();
        //add to run queue
        messageHandler.post(messageUpdater);
        //return sticky
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //stop the updating
        messageHandler.removeCallbacks(messageUpdater);
        messageDB.close();
    }

}
```

**MessageDataHelper** Class

```java
public class MessageDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Variable Declarations
    //db version
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    //database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "messageInbox.db";
    //ID column
    private static final String Home_COL = BaseColumns._ID;
    //tweet text
    private static final String Update_COL = "message_text";
    //twitter screen name
    private static final String User_COL = "user_screen";
    //time tweeted
    private static final String Time_COL = "message_time";
    //user profile image
    //private static final String User_IMG = "user_img";
    //database creation string
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE messageInbox (" + Home_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Update_COL + " TEXT, "
            + User_COL + " TEXT, " + Time_COL + " INTEGER);";
    //"   , " +
    //+ User_IMG + " TEXT);";

    MessageDataHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messageInbox");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("VACUUM");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    static ContentValues getValues(DirectMessage message){
        ContentValues messageValues = new ContentValues();
        //get the values
        try {
            //get each value from the table
            messageValues.put(Home_COL, message.getId());
            messageValues.put(Update_COL, message.getText());
            messageValues.put(User_COL, message.getSenderId());
            messageValues.put(Time_COL, message.getCreatedAt().getTime());
            //noinspection StringOperationCanBeSimplified
            //messageValues.put(User_IMG, message.getSender().getProfileImageURL().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception te) { Log.e("MessageDataHelper", te.getMessage()); }
        //return the values
        return messageValues;
    }
}
```

**MessageActivity**

```java
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //Variable declarations
    //app url
    public final static String TWIT_URL = "bioauth://";
    //Twitter instance
    private Twitter bioMessaging;
    //request token for accessing user account
    private RequestToken messageRequestToken;
    //shared preferences to store user details
    private SharedPreferences messagePrefs;
    //main view for the inbox
    private ListView messageInbox;
    //update database
    private SQLiteDatabase inboxDB;
    //cursor for handling data
    private Cursor inboxCursor;
    //adapter for mapping data
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    //for error logging
    private String LOG_TAG = "MessageActivity";
    //Broadcast receiver for when new updates are available
    private BroadcastReceiver messageStatusReceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Sets the inbox layout style using inbox_layout.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_layout);
        //setup onclick listener for tweet button
        LinearLayout newMessageClicker = findViewById(R.id.newmessagebutton);
        newMessageClicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        LinearLayout timelineClicker = findViewById(R.id.timelineButton);
        timelineClicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        //get the preferences for the app
        messagePrefs = getSharedPreferences("bioPrefs", 0);
        //get user token and secret for authentication
        //String userToken = messagePrefs.getString("user_token", null);
        //String userSecret = messagePrefs.getString("user_secret", null);
    }


    //Click listener handles sign in and tweet button presses
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //find view
        switch(v.getId()) {
            //user has pressed tweet button
            case R.id.newmessagebutton:
                //launch tweet activity
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DirectMessageClass.class));
                break;
            case R.id.timelineButton:
                //Return to timeline
                finish();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //setupInbox displays the user's Twitter messages
    private void setupInbox() {
        //setContentView(R.layout.inbox_layout); //Sets the inbox layout style using inbox_layout.xml
        /*//setup onclick listener for tweet button
        LinearLayout newMessageClicker = findViewById(R.id.newmessagebutton);
        newMessageClicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        LinearLayout timelineClicker = findViewById(R.id.timelineButton);
        timelineClicker.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        //Error catching
        try {
            //get the inbox
            //get reference to the list view
            messageInbox = findViewById(R.id.messageList);
            //instantiate database helper
            //database helper for update data
            MessageDataHelper messageHelper = new MessageDataHelper(this);
            //get the database
            inboxDB = messageHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //query the database, most recent tweets first
            inboxCursor = inboxDB.query
                    ("messageInbox", null, null, null, null, null, "message_time DESC");
            //manage the updates using a cursor
            startManagingCursor(inboxCursor);
            //instantiate adapter
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, inboxCursor);
            //this will make the app populate the new update data in the timeline view
            messageInbox.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            //instantiate receiver class for finding out when new updates are available
            messageStatusReceiver = new TwitterUpdateReceiver();
            //register for updates
            registerReceiver(messageStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter("MESSAGE_UPDATES"));
            //start the Service for updates now
            this.getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class));
        }
        catch(Exception te) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to fetch inbox: " + te.getMessage());
            notifyUser("Failed to fetch inbox");
        }
    }

    //Class to implement Broadcast receipt for new updates
    class TwitterUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int rowLimit = 50;
            if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(inboxDB, "messageInbox")>rowLimit) {
                String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM messageInbox WHERE "+ BaseColumns._ID+" NOT IN " +
                        "(SELECT "+BaseColumns._ID+" FROM messageInbox ORDER BY "+"message_time DESC " +
                        "limit "+rowLimit+")";
                inboxDB.execSQL(deleteQuery);
            }

            inboxCursor = inboxDB.query("messageInbox", null, null, null, null, null, "message_time DESC");
            startManagingCursor(inboxCursor);
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(context, inboxCursor);
            messageInbox.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            //stop the updater Service
            stopService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class));
            //remove receiver register
            unregisterReceiver(messageStatusReceiver);
            //close the database
            inboxDB.close();
        }
        catch(Exception se) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "unable to stop Service or receiver"); }
    }

    //Method to output inbox_layout to user
    private void notifyUser(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**MessageAdapter** Class

```java
public class MessageAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    //Twitter developer key
    //private final static String TWIT_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    //Twitter developer secret
    //private final static String TWIT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXX";
   //strings representing database column names to map to views
    private static final String[] from = { "message_text", "user_screen",
            "message_time" };
    //view item IDs for mapping database record values to
    private static final int[] to = { R.id.messageText, R.id.userScreen,
            R.id.messageTime,};

    //constructor sets up adapter, passing 'from' data and 'to' views
    MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, R.layout.direct_message, c, from, to);
    }

    //Bind the data to the visible views
    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(row, context, cursor);

        //get the update time
        long createdAt = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("message_time"));
        //get the update time view
        TextView textCreatedAt = row.findViewById(R.id.messageTime);
        //adjust the way the time is displayed to make it human-readable
        textCreatedAt.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(createdAt)+" ");

        //get the status ID
        long messageID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        //get the user name
        String messageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_screen"));
        //create a StatusData object to store these
        StatusData messageData = new StatusData(messageID, messageName);
        //set the status data object as tag for reply button in this view
        row.findViewById(R.id.messageReply).setTag(messageData);
        //setup onclick listeners for the retweet and reply buttons
        row.findViewById(R.id.messageReply).setOnClickListener(messageListener);
        //setup  onclick for the user screen name within the tweet
        row.findViewById(R.id.userScreen).setOnClickListener(messageListener);
    }

    // tweetListener handles clicks of reply and retweet buttons
    // also handles clicking the user name within a tweet
    private final View.OnClickListener messageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        //onClick method
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //which view was clicked
            switch (v.getId()) {
                //message reply button pressed
                case R.id.messageReply:
                    //implement reply
                    //create an intent for sending a new tweet
                    Intent messageReplyIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DirectMessageClass.class);
                    //get the data from the tag within the button view
                    StatusData messageData = (StatusData) v.getTag();
                    //pass the status ID
                    messageReplyIntent.putExtra("tweetID", messageData.getID());
                    //pass the user name
                    messageReplyIntent.putExtra("tweetUser", messageData.getUser());
                    //go to the tweet screen
                    v.getContext().startActivity(messageReplyIntent);
                    break;
                case R.id.homebutton:
                    //Add return to timeline method
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Too much code.  You need to narrow down where the error is occurring and focus on that code... not the entire application dumped on Stack Overflow.  Take the error message literally, so focus on data inserts.  Somewhere there is an insert of `messageInbox._id` that contains an existing value.  Find all inserts in code and place proper debugging code to trace values.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to forcefully insert **your own IDs** into an autoincremental ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using  UNIQUE(" + Home_COL +") ON CONFLICT REPLACE when creating the table and insertWithOnConflict instead of insertOrThrow method.